# PHP Stack trace, PHP   1. {main}(), PHP 2. include() error in apache's error_log.php

Tags: apache2, cakephp-1.3

I have a login page implemented in cakephp. It was working fine, but some days before we implemented SSL after that it is working fine on server, but I am not able to login on my local system. Moreover it is not throwing any errors, but when I looked into apache error log file it is throwing the following error ->

```
[Fri Jul 20 11:55:10 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Deprecated: 
Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in
/Backup/www/Web/SourceCode/instantmeeting/cake/libs/cache.php on line 155,
referer: /Web/SourceCode/instantmeeting/enterprise/web_user/login

[Fri Jul 20 11:55:10 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Stack trace:,
referer: /Web/SourceCode/instantmeeting/enterprise/web_user/login

[Fri Jul 20 11:55:10 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP   1. {main}()
/Backup/www/Web/SourceCode/instantmeeting/app/webroot/index.php:0,
referer: /Web/SourceCode/instantmeeting/enterprise/web_user/login

[Fri Jul 20 11:55:10 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP   2. include()
/Backup/www/Web/SourceCode/instantmeeting/app/webroot/index.php:81,
referer: /Web/SourceCode/instantmeeting/enterprise/web_user/login
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a PHP5 deprecated ERROR.

This happens becuase you may be trying to pass an object by value not by reference.
This used to be possible in PHP4, but is now deprecated as PHP5 follows more strict OOP principles.

> In most programming languages, an object can be passed to functions or
>   other objects by reference, not by value. In other words, rather than
>   passing a new object with the same values, the actual object is
>   passed, meaning changes are kept.

I would suggest that there is something like (this is just an example):
In PHP4 this code would output Jason because you'd basically be passing a copy of $var:

```
class Man{
    var $Name;
}
function aaaa($Man){
    $Man->Name = 'Boby';
}
$var = new Man();
$var->Name = 'Jason';
aaa($var); // Passing an Object **by value**
echo $var->Name; // Will output Jason
```

Because of this you had to manualy pass it by reference to the `aaa()` function like:

```
aaa(&$var);
echo $var->Name; // Will output Boby
```

**This will work without the reference in PHP5!**
What is your PHP version on the server? You should upgrade and check out what is there on line 155 in `/Backup/www/Web/SourceCode/instantmeeting/cake/libs/cache.php`